# A report that uses tablix returns error when trying to deploy to Report Server 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-tablix

We have some reports that have been built using tablixes, and tested in a 2008 Report Server. When trying to deploy to Report Server 2005 (don't ask why) we get an error saying

The report definition is not valid. Details: The element 'ReportItems' in namespace 'XXXXXX' has invalid child element 'Tablix'

So.. what is the issue? I guess 2005 does not support tablixes.. And we cannot upgrade the server version. So the real question is.. is there a workaround for this to avoid having to remake those reports for 2005??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find there are other more subtle issues with your reports if you develop in a higher version than you have in production.

If you are stuck with using ssrs2005 in production, can you find a copy of visual studio that supports it.  It may be a clunky interface, but you wont get surprises going into prod...